# dompdf not displaying image generated by PHP file

Tags: php, codeigniter, dompdf

I'm using dompdf to generate a PDF file. In the file I'm including an image that is generated on the fly by PHP by using;

`<img src="image.php" />`

When I view the page I can see an error saying "Image not found" which links to the supposedly not found image which displays fine when you click on it.

I've tried adding a .png extension to the page generating the image but that doesn't make any difference. I've also saved the generated image to the server and linked to that instead and it works fine.

The only method I can think of to solve this is to save the image on the server and then link to that. Ideally, I don't want to do this so I was wondering if anybody had come across this before or if anyone can think of a fix for it.

The version of dompdf I'm using is 0.6.0 beta 3 and I'm using it with CodeIgniter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How are you loading your HTML document into dompdf? `$dompdf->load_html()`? `$dompdf->load_html_file()`? To access a PHP-generated image you should be using the latter. Additionally, unless you are loading the document through a web server dompdf will grab the file itself, not the rendered file. Since image.php is not a valid image type dompdf will fail to load it.

There are two solutions:

1. Load your document through your web server, e.g. `$dompdf->load_html_file('http://example.com/mydoc.html');`. When you do this the image reference will be interpreted as `http://example.com/image.php`.
2. Reference your image using a full URL (including domain) so that your server processes it before sending it back to dompdf, e.g. `<img src="http://example.com/image.php" />`.

Comment: I'm not sure I can use load_html_file because the actual file with the contents I want to load is stored outside the web root and it has PHP that needs to be executed in it.

I've tried with the absolute/relative URLs too but it doesn't seem to make a difference. I guess I'll have to look at generating the image and saving it on the server.

Comment: That's probably the easiest way to tackle it in this situation. Another option would be to encode the image in base64 and use a data uri. Then you wouldn't have to worry about saving the image (though dompdf would need to be able to do so).

Comment: The data uri idea worked perfectly and meant I didn't have to generate an image for each PDF when they would probably only be viewed the once. Cheers!

Comment: To access a PHP-generated image from a PHP-generated html file, change "DOMPDF_ENABLE_REMOTE" to true. The text "image.php is not a valid image type" did not make so much sense (it's just a name and the content decides), until I realized that you'd get the PHP file itself, unless you remote was enabled.

Answer (score 3):

First add this tag `img src="image.php"`, you need to specify the complete root where is located your image, so it most end in the format required like JPG or PNG, etc., and in the configuration file (`dompdf_config.inc.php`) you need to change this line `DOMPDF_ENABLE_REMOTE` , which his default value is false change it to true and that is all :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use as an alternative supported the Base64 image data

```
$html = '<div>
    <p>IMAGE</p>
    <img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAMgAAABMCAIAAACnG28HAAAABmJLR0QA/wD/AP%2BgvaeTAAAACXBIWXMAAAsTAAALEwEAmpwYAAAAB3RJTUUH1AgeBS42B7vBqgAAEhBJREFUeNrtnd%2BPHEcVhfcfBoknxAOIh0g88EsIIqKI1UprObYVe23FwQmskO0EYSskkCgkEo5MCMgoGBABhBDkIXzV3%2Byh6Onu6ZnZ2Zm1u1Qa9fb0VFfdOvfcW7du9%2B59NpWpbKDsTSKYygSsqUzAmsoErKlMZQLWVDZeHj3%2B67vvf/DSjZcODy/%2B9N5bH374O85MwJrKWpACT/vPfe%2B5Z5/97re/8cxXv/L1rz3DwcEPngdhS8FrAtZUZgWWuvHiJcBkBVugivrlL30RbB0eHLx5784ErKksUWCj6zd/DHqAEZD6wuc/x8GNo6uvvnLLPwGZZnEC1lSWsH1CSnKyiq3LV657Ust45dLFCVhTGVXACoiJOyWe8LHEmSdfu3NbK7krphBtgDzp0zR/uynSt3/xJl65AKLKVaDq4YN3WQny%2Bdrxy5cv7MNb1KXs4AaBRc/UhqX4cyrDnhCOjjhgptfHKI3IVVR569Wb1/78x0f1ZWCL88BrKbraFLAgT/CkNkzAOi2uCqqs6/AWremtp7Log8D%2B/emnrSvhLSC1LKo2AixFoD8ItQIv2GtCxvp0VTvXiHcdqbLcC6RwzJkjUTUPLI1Pi8a2Ayw6gaMXKbBqBfUTMtYsPzq%2BG08IF3sdYIFRHCmNIKjieAVC2gKwGLBeocCi6whlQsb6RkBPKLGAldUV10qMGlXHi9pEn08fWFAUfhXunr0HYRDYClw6lRpYiLQ2hQh22WVaC6OGFZisDU3N6QMLDaC7ki0uIeZ8ijisDyzE6GIo2GKFtEJT%2BOz8lnZ0rTbnpZw%2BsDDYAAvG0n%2BffKz1S4lPHl3Vu8AOruy8S1dx/7Ekm%2BvzBhjrzu2oFxXSegrtIFNo8slptebGi8DSxwJYnYu44RWAnKd3hSt8noDFgI3YylhQ7kYHsGvUgutDRbtgbkTBGfVqHe0CWDAWKiosXBsuuySiJ86IaTBM0EYVfm8Twi2kdfOaw8DZWs0bOHcFGDHZKBKONkNGnUAYxyCM84hFyawWJsAIACwhlbSWpRKkErsCVTS1ocXgqQELYSFBPiMvIEXFfkvd5og9DVwFaJgwgcUB3gxjRxRMP9gqJw8vMrsYtWUTMrkeaBp5j/PO8XjKYXYuX7lOf6iJiO4osPQhkKYsTeVPrD49dksnOWJPPGMxcGadITNnVNDDkJMj4CauAikr5cOLLM24YAy83B%2BkmsHilk4ChOPJL0FRezhgB51WWrZ6Jp/1ZacMLG9MR8ETyocmISM6ypgRKF3hJFUfa6nxOxJNhgdb9LuXWqww8abzFhAcHMBS2kGEAHPzybclntdooJeBswHOkKLkmGRyBlL672XP%2BJVb4912usHd458AbmuSF6ia8mxH6iLzSTf4oV2iemD/6Wrn/O6toJ2aOW42k2YjShMZEFlR2ZvXSip%2B42xyfgxEVPE4Afyc1pbNs14fUnT14YN3A%2B5RJubCPl1ljvkEOoh7ngw4w/lco6D6RqdyImQFIra0X5wxpZPKwch4AQ26Tk%2BSTNDZqn3n/cpbJ0Ir9eqxzQ95OWDRxYLxkxVftgXMkPFYgDsGBIFAF4JDolYvNRY2qM%2B7vp1a2AEukGPMduKTP8cAy0cP6HCBQoOqgYsLtnBAGzeLWl9cBw6iVCYg6E4IMs4HWMhqpHAYSCDVh5sxNZAKn4FsRsQ6YHVgaafqXAvgRaOCLGk9iQ4HeXDmwhminYAy9IsetKS/Ylzt%2BGUmfrgPBggcnQZoTGobfXOMdBgRj4kDF5f0xUsynG6WOQUCywi7Bitg0k%2BP255pljMWylbrNkBFnYyV9UFCskJKh0fLiCIxlr4O7I20EfRP60brrf1wBCq8vHEQrX5wfnjxwvSE8OpURj3NdRx/WgYfwEUPuk8E6gw3MrPbboxZc%2Bity1gjyYMuCSyxVQMr6Ubqlaprl2orlulX2n3oT%2BxjmH4SFcs%2BT3ysaHgsieRE/0NRAzO7N9Ka6HUiRK1bJ%2Bu4qVlvaTEA/hy4vaE/fbUAK7lc8lbfnA0YOL9i8kLdzGIf%2Bem0mk4pT4iVYcZKvNHJGOkL0gfDEGipZldUgQOjCXmmTzAhVfQWAcZbiGAV1HwnvUWfI1VvCgliJOyQuZ0ROHBDhTtoiurBsvtyeyPpKls0A7k76mISHR0DEhzYeWC%2BXf3q9TMeBpDgqiOHctTs1rwCBaQwj1o1lftGv3XXOkPVZpGrM67gCsM3JC%2Bj9PWc66P3/HykuPWf4u%2B7LcNYolc6UjTeyhLWSuq81wZrHlj0vH7YZp6iTGwPdBC4Se6nG4jfGxWaO7H6w8sQembcIT4BUkBMfTYIgSrEJFwLIG1riQ438TANTQ0soVPWI4cXW0B3kW/QSAIID80nSZs6xmQbfNLvKUGBJm7E%2Bb6eM1K9n9Dh2AX10VUDyPGxuIU%2BUFZCfQnmDM2u1gvDeXut6aj99NrpLl7Bhf0zSAtYzFiJrTGRCy9m%2BhlqGMsVYqezopSpSopZj8YgVnEgjZkqGF%2BEmYhj28pTM28JROpdImLuwidnuFErJmlwAQCpNgafjAWI2oGlg3ZwZqxHeNAWqJfGaZYBIlVm1ycaYvcl74GbcnHNQ/M7hsgQgegDBHy6xdK/wD2D2M3eMF0Z%2BdXej0lgldjVmFnc%2BcJ%2BJ7CQiHbdAbccqZJ700TLbIc%2BIDKBRZc8qRaGROP8JhjGDHEXLqDyFcdxlrkdf7oE0wjSfon33LwmNAV93xzbtxmLH10dE84w5KPCcGujMHw6Rs3TcNRUz8Gn/5KhAExb14BXuuQ1RmWZAsMis0SmTWbLjAKWCyUty8g9y%2BL6Nb/SXTDKPG8p9FXjqM5fYOK8sFPiwUSdsl2LyTBB%2BEb3qzAWNq4Ji3ClJpW7a%2B9KmKBZOkiW5mX4fJGbfX3%2BuxbfaOcYYKlsVCOfCTQUvT04CLWDieFMGDPfW4v/vvCNN9KdUM7zHL8FYM3oCt1F40cn67nPkzBptjJi5lrgKM9Ddpn8YlKPX3YdpDjyGEnCE9ISkhVAQiE7/16vz6TLrGlzf9OMA7uXuxsf575uJIubedAYbRf0C/dVwlXJpzXBQUPM%2BcT/Mt8D2DL/s14YdmYlMZCEA9x%2BVoddIpzN1u3egGuFFAqRsvgah3F3LeQS5WgkpvafamA5VC7rbM0ncd3ZqJdIkpCkqF4ar6LGC6bb3ggACQK7YdTbQRkkaw2Nm2o15C1JrtUx2oz2c%2BVAVMLN6YQP1KJoiLLStVqouuq5tJegA8clTD2IbLfgEhJDOGeTHrc3HCPWYI3xrspyrPFD9cQ17fEW494qU9lCJ4wr%2B1ZeXIaO8ll7x3r9%2BkbaIykhe5dBYRaYTqr%2BU1ntN6gquwJzm/wGO0r/T%2BLjncAKgnXd%2BhxtWVkfDgRrlAWWK2i9BaNHC%2BOIrhaTOaLrSUUaA6sH7b6rb0e9ZWDp9srhC7tiKpIKoVK6wgqw9B7qELPIkDY6H5XkJ1HomhXcUpXJZslPjc8emqxVX7eJani9cFvjHrlQ6iQJJs98Ms1Wa6u4LLuaZW/SBFrus8sCjY6m1uWLNSrqKwjUDUfR56gZ8TGU6Ps53EuVvdSBAdbUjMSdXee5sdMBFjSQVdsAY%2BmySFEGymfT2Tg38YSCnpnvfLKtUczcyc5Gi64Uh3vSLaGL2gA3gdAS15kzbcWkNvgwwm7OxfyVLRNsCqjOQEhLdPpkW%2BJkIs8tFLXFITt2ac90j1o/pcawKVci8M5sC8677SEEdf%2BL2jdRXBclA7FcA3XZh90ysLTojFzvpLZl2Ycya0Kzkuf/Y1nqxUhc7HjfmhsbT4ZgeEtcZs9h3lYmcFrvznaaNt%2BaYgJnsppokzN9gWaBZbw0mTBJLEYstY8l6MNhMTeJoRfao7Vml62tkM2TATOfr0GYgdmkScnrehQ2aMTcZY2LviTh9FlDlbAG1jZNoeKT0rPg15thwFKFU5X95pbgijfQCE49Q76xhrNlQWPLdD%2BNMKn3Sjy8zQXzInNhmFBWNs46sWJ%2BFX3OLiRtDguFn8y8sWaHx/18408mQWjCXM0Z6w%2BHJS1OMvaNGvMkobdk1fKaEpP9YF0ILZ0%2BiUEfV3yCVehnd6jTTy2W/YT7Hf42gaWW64zXxF7vtCdVpnMDUV9EWjLiYAacjCWN%2B21B6ouXCi9euY4IkpI6sHuvnxGuEit99lr%2By17nsGWv49euSSWtbPjotImA2YMJTQA5cTW9LgMcbn32EYlEWGxis1Zl4EJZUIokCYnPFsVKq2aBa4s7TaGzEGLTnm7Zx8quZ5IY67fehPMHNp7UlfrJVYGl7chDrUJqFoY9ySM1ublvIS1jOZ3GlwcCImptYuUjQycMKhPPb%2BlPFm609r9XvjZ%2BNOThOlHJFG%2B9mfWBbV3xBJhMBcvuoV6dPCSk%2Bp6oCefp2psU2eItlcoFPkNQu7a8KtQqaQVmWUcnK/zZY/%2BL3h0oM%2Bmc%2BvM6yCn/S/KumRNechEwMH4DV/bBXaPhnXlR4n7%2ByD18hu/mvxsv9DZzxu2yVhBJySQ2rDCSEvQWXCrWXp0UyHmaNW1maJHRtFCEeXQVbLUuFlh5Rmj7prAm0iAgzwUMjLaTWuoHDF0AhrRUUF14HVWnanjwyqt4xE2Ec2RnVkgL6Uxniyl0R8V8qQS7l21/9lLGhqv09JMOZcvDChMfrk9t3PBOFslOAKveHzBfZ1nZmTCZJz2SgWToUt/CBZGU5kpnx1/URs/jC%2BPIn8rTRAh2IYwG%2BtM3NbNNqsbZjU%2B8ibdhrQKsNeXlO0KCmzqyYMRSnVstTXGLwNLp3PG3f81sTpPEoU%2B88mtqdgtYWWGZI%2BourJ6m/6Tls3NYDN9nM3TH30yBxuq2J8D2JDBW7cW7gNLY%2ByjiOX0LjY5jWf1duT7m2bKt9zbeyCzi%2BGQwVgxicjtdBJ3Tl2aVvaYmJd8IPmSw46%2BVE1h5%2Bqi8FXbriX6nji3reX%2BJcr1d2PmczA7yax58op7NC9Knf3myuo8lsOY3j7dV/vaX33eqgYHuAGv7Oe%2BbLv9pyjmC1L/%2B8fizk3wBfWEfpdTN%2BvV7b3gZB1QvbhXO//bhr6he/M5br99//ZiDV2/d%2BuFLR9Y7xzdblZNewDHXW/ktP/T47u2fcMy3nrHlAEsfK9aQP89A7Htno0ZKWYkzZgSBmC6/UNwuKsdKCol//OjhhvQ4srYznPcr7uhNc96Tdphf%2BUOmzQ7X%2BfjuRzF53/nWN1t1//nvOzqrZ6jzV/pV5/lTqebz5Mk8jsWroIxknJ3UWv9XARaT6nTWRNqpbZ18GwWKxuSgFmuT13dQiy9S7pQp1zuLN66%2BoAjqe1Gjzd6OUXBlKj8cnsXWtxx7uzETbHCIAZl6kMwCSOXo2g3asTJeqs36Z0TBZV55fHzbevfuz/ikEQ6ohRffef/%2BvfvUN37%2BNn%2B%2B994DD7wsLdgsB/xJB%2BoGvSxvXM7CsESk9/9vUjpHna9ovJatxCnXRlfn6WCvT3y06KS2MMTJ8WrnADJmRqt0WgWp/eajj5WmIuYnSyklN6qPlbhC8e7MEI1zd9oXAV7g9NfVn1jpCT9Jn%2Bkk1ciccSwfIm2FsmLic/DJ3/9JzQUcO941WYFf1c32LTWSXG%2B4QR/rwQcfRfKP//TJoz885jjIZuCZMpCEKLQwHMi%2BfVUuoBZgpRO0wgTQHE0MTyRTwj1UC7tIz2yEA8/U8lrTqNMglQkGHAqCT44Ljf/yHaXDBc5WLeu%2B%2B7bmtXVmeLZkLJPJ9F12/JWFyZrMI0wLF%2Ba13BR%2BJhdBCUFORlelTzVWftlbKHd/Xxjr3n0xvlD0T3zx8cPkbox/GHpry9iT51zM7dloEFHkTeGG1UNZeQ7Ct07sbG/zTpe8nOgMgroTsFYpeSWOby7Z8ZCvGbnZK5yAtdPAmqV9jk5N22LxscRkZpfHIauHhH0v5gSsXSlmUJ2L7Skjunn/Vt447MtRzKKegDWVVTzCkpJ1eDGvfjRb32f4NmTKJ2A9FcWnhvKWnrwrS4RtYh99AtZTUcqLSU8eAa/fpy17TYw1ldWtoW5W3ouc9yX3vZRlAtZUFhcfi8q/PMlrz/2/hxOwprKWNfTB2sTfh9%2BBPQFrKmOtoU/x5%2BVQG32qYgLW00Va/vcb/z3nRu81AevpKr5tYPi9EhOwprK7ZQLWVCZgTeX8lP8CuDenorrKqfIAAAAASUVORK5CYII%3D">
</div>':

require_once('dompdf/dompdf_config.inc.php');
$dompdf = new DOMPDF ();
$dompdf->load_html ($html);
$dompdf->render ();
$dompdf->stream ("Test.pdf", array ("Attachment" => false));
```

Get the image from php in base64:

```
//getIMG.php?data=1&id=123
if ($data == 1) {
    echo "data:image/".$adj->type.";base64,"
            .str_replace ("\n", "", base64_encode ($adj->imageBinary));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 

 //Use this code to convert your image to base64
 // Apply this in a view 
  
$path = base_url('images/your_img.png');// Modify this part (your_img.png
$type = pathinfo($path, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
$data = file_get_contents($path);
$base64 = 'data:image/' . $type . ';base64,' . base64_encode($data); <br>
?>

// using image tag that will output to the browser.

<img src="<?=$base64?>" /> // This will output the image in pdf to the browser.
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.