# DOMPDF is not generating dynamic image using PHP

Tags: php, image, dompdf

I am generating a pdf using DOMPDF but in that the image is not displaying instead it is throwing an error "Image not found".

Here is my code :

```
require_once "dompdf_config.inc.php";
require_once('html2_pdf_lib/html2pdf.class.php');
include_once('../config.php');
$file = "www/test/mytest.php"; 
$html=file_get_contents($file);

$dompdf = new DOMPDF();
//$dompdf->load_html($my_html);
$dompdf->load_html_file('https://www.lettertowomen.com/admin/dompdf/www/test/mytest.php?id=111');
$dompdf->render();
$dompdf->stream("sample.pdf");
```

mytest.php

```
<body>
<form action="" method="POST">                  
                    <table width="1000" height="1000" style="background-color: #b91781;font-family: 'DejaVuSerif'; color: #ffffff;font-size: 20px;">
                    <tbody><tr>
                      <td width="249" valign="middle" align="center">
                      <div style="height: 595; width: 249; text-align: left;padding-top:140px;">
                      <img src="<?php echo base_url;?>uploads/<?php echo $result['image'];?>" style="border-radius: 159px;
                        width: 159px; height:225px;margin:70px auto 0;">
                        </div>
                      </td>
                      <td width="583" valign="middle" align="center">
                      <div style="height: 188px; width: 448px; text-align: left;">
                        <span style="display: block;
                        float: left;">To <span style="font-size: 22px; font-weight: 700; line-height: 34px; position: relative; top: 17px;"><?php echo $result['recipient_name'];?></span>
                      </span><br><br>
                    <div style="clear: both; display: inline-block; min-height: 160px; padding: 0px 18px; margin: 28px auto 0px;color: #ffffff">From the day you were born,<br>
                    I fell in love with you my girl.<br>
                    And when you bloomed like a rose without a single thorn,<br>
                    You turned my entire life into a most precious pearl.<br>
                    Your love and care for me is a beautiful dawn,<br>
                    That marks the end of darkness left to unfurl.<br><br>

                    Feeling blessed to have you as my daughter. </div>
                    <br><br>
                    <span style="display: block;
                         float: right;">From<span style="font-size: 22px; font-weight: 700; line-height: 34px; position: relative; top: 18px;"><?php echo $result['sender_name'];?></span> 
                      </span></div>
                      </td>
                      </tr>
                    </tbody></table>

                    </form>

</body>
                    </html>
```

everything is displaying but image is not displayed. I have check already asked question in stackoverflow : [dompdf not displaying image generated by PHP file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11360603/dompdf-not-displaying-image-generated-by-php-file) but it is not working in my case

Also I have set `DOMPDF_ENABLE_REMOTE = true`

Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm not getting the same error when I render the document at that URL. Do you have read/write permission to the temp directory? Did PHP throw any errors?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Base64 image data

```
$html = '<div>
    <p>IMAGE</p>
    <img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAMgAAABMCAIAAACnG28HAAAABmJLR0QA/wD/AP%2BgvaeTAAAACXBIWXMAAAsTAAALEwEAmpwYAAAAB3RJTUUH1AgeBS42B7vBqgAAEhBJREFUeNrtnd%2BPHEcVhfcfBoknxAOIh0g88EsIIqKI1UprObYVe23FwQmskO0EYSskkCgkEo5MCMgoGBABhBDkIXzV3%2Byh6Onu6ZnZ2Zm1u1Qa9fb0VFfdOvfcW7du9%2B59NpWpbKDsTSKYygSsqUzAmsoErKlMZQLWVDZeHj3%2B67vvf/DSjZcODy/%2B9N5bH374O85MwJrKWpACT/vPfe%2B5Z5/97re/8cxXv/L1rz3DwcEPngdhS8FrAtZUZgWWuvHiJcBkBVugivrlL30RbB0eHLx5784ErKksUWCj6zd/DHqAEZD6wuc/x8GNo6uvvnLLPwGZZnEC1lSWsH1CSnKyiq3LV657Ust45dLFCVhTGVXACoiJOyWe8LHEmSdfu3NbK7krphBtgDzp0zR/uynSt3/xJl65AKLKVaDq4YN3WQny%2Bdrxy5cv7MNb1KXs4AaBRc/UhqX4cyrDnhCOjjhgptfHKI3IVVR569Wb1/78x0f1ZWCL88BrKbraFLAgT/CkNkzAOi2uCqqs6/AWremtp7Log8D%2B/emnrSvhLSC1LKo2AixFoD8ItQIv2GtCxvp0VTvXiHcdqbLcC6RwzJkjUTUPLI1Pi8a2Ayw6gaMXKbBqBfUTMtYsPzq%2BG08IF3sdYIFRHCmNIKjieAVC2gKwGLBeocCi6whlQsb6RkBPKLGAldUV10qMGlXHi9pEn08fWFAUfhXunr0HYRDYClw6lRpYiLQ2hQh22WVaC6OGFZisDU3N6QMLDaC7ki0uIeZ8ijisDyzE6GIo2GKFtEJT%2BOz8lnZ0rTbnpZw%2BsDDYAAvG0n%2BffKz1S4lPHl3Vu8AOruy8S1dx/7Ekm%2BvzBhjrzu2oFxXSegrtIFNo8slptebGi8DSxwJYnYu44RWAnKd3hSt8noDFgI3YylhQ7kYHsGvUgutDRbtgbkTBGfVqHe0CWDAWKiosXBsuuySiJ86IaTBM0EYVfm8Twi2kdfOaw8DZWs0bOHcFGDHZKBKONkNGnUAYxyCM84hFyawWJsAIACwhlbSWpRKkErsCVTS1ocXgqQELYSFBPiMvIEXFfkvd5og9DVwFaJgwgcUB3gxjRxRMP9gqJw8vMrsYtWUTMrkeaBp5j/PO8XjKYXYuX7lOf6iJiO4osPQhkKYsTeVPrD49dksnOWJPPGMxcGadITNnVNDDkJMj4CauAikr5cOLLM24YAy83B%2BkmsHilk4ChOPJL0FRezhgB51WWrZ6Jp/1ZacMLG9MR8ETyocmISM6ypgRKF3hJFUfa6nxOxJNhgdb9LuXWqww8abzFhAcHMBS2kGEAHPzybclntdooJeBswHOkKLkmGRyBlL672XP%2BJVb4912usHd458AbmuSF6ia8mxH6iLzSTf4oV2iemD/6Wrn/O6toJ2aOW42k2YjShMZEFlR2ZvXSip%2B42xyfgxEVPE4Afyc1pbNs14fUnT14YN3A%2B5RJubCPl1ljvkEOoh7ngw4w/lco6D6RqdyImQFIra0X5wxpZPKwch4AQ26Tk%2BSTNDZqn3n/cpbJ0Ir9eqxzQ95OWDRxYLxkxVftgXMkPFYgDsGBIFAF4JDolYvNRY2qM%2B7vp1a2AEukGPMduKTP8cAy0cP6HCBQoOqgYsLtnBAGzeLWl9cBw6iVCYg6E4IMs4HWMhqpHAYSCDVh5sxNZAKn4FsRsQ6YHVgaafqXAvgRaOCLGk9iQ4HeXDmwhminYAy9IsetKS/Ylzt%2BGUmfrgPBggcnQZoTGobfXOMdBgRj4kDF5f0xUsynG6WOQUCywi7Bitg0k%2BP255pljMWylbrNkBFnYyV9UFCskJKh0fLiCIxlr4O7I20EfRP60brrf1wBCq8vHEQrX5wfnjxwvSE8OpURj3NdRx/WgYfwEUPuk8E6gw3MrPbboxZc%2Bity1gjyYMuCSyxVQMr6Ubqlaprl2orlulX2n3oT%2BxjmH4SFcs%2BT3ysaHgsieRE/0NRAzO7N9Ka6HUiRK1bJ%2Bu4qVlvaTEA/hy4vaE/fbUAK7lc8lbfnA0YOL9i8kLdzGIf%2Bem0mk4pT4iVYcZKvNHJGOkL0gfDEGipZldUgQOjCXmmTzAhVfQWAcZbiGAV1HwnvUWfI1VvCgliJOyQuZ0ROHBDhTtoiurBsvtyeyPpKls0A7k76mISHR0DEhzYeWC%2BXf3q9TMeBpDgqiOHctTs1rwCBaQwj1o1lftGv3XXOkPVZpGrM67gCsM3JC%2Bj9PWc66P3/HykuPWf4u%2B7LcNYolc6UjTeyhLWSuq81wZrHlj0vH7YZp6iTGwPdBC4Se6nG4jfGxWaO7H6w8sQembcIT4BUkBMfTYIgSrEJFwLIG1riQ438TANTQ0soVPWI4cXW0B3kW/QSAIID80nSZs6xmQbfNLvKUGBJm7E%2Bb6eM1K9n9Dh2AX10VUDyPGxuIU%2BUFZCfQnmDM2u1gvDeXut6aj99NrpLl7Bhf0zSAtYzFiJrTGRCy9m%2BhlqGMsVYqezopSpSopZj8YgVnEgjZkqGF%2BEmYhj28pTM28JROpdImLuwidnuFErJmlwAQCpNgafjAWI2oGlg3ZwZqxHeNAWqJfGaZYBIlVm1ycaYvcl74GbcnHNQ/M7hsgQgegDBHy6xdK/wD2D2M3eMF0Z%2BdXej0lgldjVmFnc%2BcJ%2BJ7CQiHbdAbccqZJ700TLbIc%2BIDKBRZc8qRaGROP8JhjGDHEXLqDyFcdxlrkdf7oE0wjSfon33LwmNAV93xzbtxmLH10dE84w5KPCcGujMHw6Rs3TcNRUz8Gn/5KhAExb14BXuuQ1RmWZAsMis0SmTWbLjAKWCyUty8g9y%2BL6Nb/SXTDKPG8p9FXjqM5fYOK8sFPiwUSdsl2LyTBB%2BEb3qzAWNq4Ji3ClJpW7a%2B9KmKBZOkiW5mX4fJGbfX3%2BuxbfaOcYYKlsVCOfCTQUvT04CLWDieFMGDPfW4v/vvCNN9KdUM7zHL8FYM3oCt1F40cn67nPkzBptjJi5lrgKM9Ddpn8YlKPX3YdpDjyGEnCE9ISkhVAQiE7/16vz6TLrGlzf9OMA7uXuxsf575uJIubedAYbRf0C/dVwlXJpzXBQUPM%2BcT/Mt8D2DL/s14YdmYlMZCEA9x%2BVoddIpzN1u3egGuFFAqRsvgah3F3LeQS5WgkpvafamA5VC7rbM0ncd3ZqJdIkpCkqF4ar6LGC6bb3ggACQK7YdTbQRkkaw2Nm2o15C1JrtUx2oz2c%2BVAVMLN6YQP1KJoiLLStVqouuq5tJegA8clTD2IbLfgEhJDOGeTHrc3HCPWYI3xrspyrPFD9cQ17fEW494qU9lCJ4wr%2B1ZeXIaO8ll7x3r9%2BkbaIykhe5dBYRaYTqr%2BU1ntN6gquwJzm/wGO0r/T%2BLjncAKgnXd%2BhxtWVkfDgRrlAWWK2i9BaNHC%2BOIrhaTOaLrSUUaA6sH7b6rb0e9ZWDp9srhC7tiKpIKoVK6wgqw9B7qELPIkDY6H5XkJ1HomhXcUpXJZslPjc8emqxVX7eJani9cFvjHrlQ6iQJJs98Ms1Wa6u4LLuaZW/SBFrus8sCjY6m1uWLNSrqKwjUDUfR56gZ8TGU6Ps53EuVvdSBAdbUjMSdXee5sdMBFjSQVdsAY%2BmySFEGymfT2Tg38YSCnpnvfLKtUczcyc5Gi64Uh3vSLaGL2gA3gdAS15kzbcWkNvgwwm7OxfyVLRNsCqjOQEhLdPpkW%2BJkIs8tFLXFITt2ac90j1o/pcawKVci8M5sC8677SEEdf%2BL2jdRXBclA7FcA3XZh90ysLTojFzvpLZl2Ycya0Kzkuf/Y1nqxUhc7HjfmhsbT4ZgeEtcZs9h3lYmcFrvznaaNt%2BaYgJnsppokzN9gWaBZbw0mTBJLEYstY8l6MNhMTeJoRfao7Vml62tkM2TATOfr0GYgdmkScnrehQ2aMTcZY2LviTh9FlDlbAG1jZNoeKT0rPg15thwFKFU5X95pbgijfQCE49Q76xhrNlQWPLdD%2BNMKn3Sjy8zQXzInNhmFBWNs46sWJ%2BFX3OLiRtDguFn8y8sWaHx/18408mQWjCXM0Z6w%2BHJS1OMvaNGvMkobdk1fKaEpP9YF0ILZ0%2BiUEfV3yCVehnd6jTTy2W/YT7Hf42gaWW64zXxF7vtCdVpnMDUV9EWjLiYAacjCWN%2B21B6ouXCi9euY4IkpI6sHuvnxGuEit99lr%2By17nsGWv49euSSWtbPjotImA2YMJTQA5cTW9LgMcbn32EYlEWGxis1Zl4EJZUIokCYnPFsVKq2aBa4s7TaGzEGLTnm7Zx8quZ5IY67fehPMHNp7UlfrJVYGl7chDrUJqFoY9ySM1ublvIS1jOZ3GlwcCImptYuUjQycMKhPPb%2BlPFm609r9XvjZ%2BNOThOlHJFG%2B9mfWBbV3xBJhMBcvuoV6dPCSk%2Bp6oCefp2psU2eItlcoFPkNQu7a8KtQqaQVmWUcnK/zZY/%2BL3h0oM%2Bmc%2BvM6yCn/S/KumRNechEwMH4DV/bBXaPhnXlR4n7%2ByD18hu/mvxsv9DZzxu2yVhBJySQ2rDCSEvQWXCrWXp0UyHmaNW1maJHRtFCEeXQVbLUuFlh5Rmj7prAm0iAgzwUMjLaTWuoHDF0AhrRUUF14HVWnanjwyqt4xE2Ec2RnVkgL6Uxniyl0R8V8qQS7l21/9lLGhqv09JMOZcvDChMfrk9t3PBOFslOAKveHzBfZ1nZmTCZJz2SgWToUt/CBZGU5kpnx1/URs/jC%2BPIn8rTRAh2IYwG%2BtM3NbNNqsbZjU%2B8ibdhrQKsNeXlO0KCmzqyYMRSnVstTXGLwNLp3PG3f81sTpPEoU%2B88mtqdgtYWWGZI%2BourJ6m/6Tls3NYDN9nM3TH30yBxuq2J8D2JDBW7cW7gNLY%2ByjiOX0LjY5jWf1duT7m2bKt9zbeyCzi%2BGQwVgxicjtdBJ3Tl2aVvaYmJd8IPmSw46%2BVE1h5%2Bqi8FXbriX6nji3reX%2BJcr1d2PmczA7yax58op7NC9Knf3myuo8lsOY3j7dV/vaX33eqgYHuAGv7Oe%2BbLv9pyjmC1L/%2B8fizk3wBfWEfpdTN%2BvV7b3gZB1QvbhXO//bhr6he/M5br99//ZiDV2/d%2BuFLR9Y7xzdblZNewDHXW/ktP/T47u2fcMy3nrHlAEsfK9aQP89A7Htno0ZKWYkzZgSBmC6/UNwuKsdKCol//OjhhvQ4srYznPcr7uhNc96Tdphf%2BUOmzQ7X%2BfjuRzF53/nWN1t1//nvOzqrZ6jzV/pV5/lTqebz5Mk8jsWroIxknJ3UWv9XARaT6nTWRNqpbZ18GwWKxuSgFmuT13dQiy9S7pQp1zuLN66%2BoAjqe1Gjzd6OUXBlKj8cnsXWtxx7uzETbHCIAZl6kMwCSOXo2g3asTJeqs36Z0TBZV55fHzbevfuz/ikEQ6ohRffef/%2BvfvUN37%2BNn%2B%2B994DD7wsLdgsB/xJB%2BoGvSxvXM7CsESk9/9vUjpHna9ovJatxCnXRlfn6WCvT3y06KS2MMTJ8WrnADJmRqt0WgWp/eajj5WmIuYnSyklN6qPlbhC8e7MEI1zd9oXAV7g9NfVn1jpCT9Jn%2Bkk1ciccSwfIm2FsmLic/DJ3/9JzQUcO941WYFf1c32LTWSXG%2B4QR/rwQcfRfKP//TJoz885jjIZuCZMpCEKLQwHMi%2BfVUuoBZgpRO0wgTQHE0MTyRTwj1UC7tIz2yEA8/U8lrTqNMglQkGHAqCT44Ljf/yHaXDBc5WLeu%2B%2B7bmtXVmeLZkLJPJ9F12/JWFyZrMI0wLF%2Ba13BR%2BJhdBCUFORlelTzVWftlbKHd/Xxjr3n0xvlD0T3zx8cPkbox/GHpry9iT51zM7dloEFHkTeGG1UNZeQ7Ct07sbG/zTpe8nOgMgroTsFYpeSWOby7Z8ZCvGbnZK5yAtdPAmqV9jk5N22LxscRkZpfHIauHhH0v5gSsXSlmUJ2L7Skjunn/Vt447MtRzKKegDWVVTzCkpJ1eDGvfjRb32f4NmTKJ2A9FcWnhvKWnrwrS4RtYh99AtZTUcqLSU8eAa/fpy17TYw1ldWtoW5W3ouc9yX3vZRlAtZUFhcfi8q/PMlrz/2/hxOwprKWNfTB2sTfh9%2BBPQFrKmOtoU/x5%2BVQG32qYgLW00Va/vcb/z3nRu81AevpKr5tYPi9EhOwprK7ZQLWVCZgTeX8lP8CuDenorrKqfIAAAAASUVORK5CYII%3D">
</div>':

require_once('dompdf/dompdf_config.inc.php');
$dompdf = new DOMPDF ();
$dompdf->load_html ($html);
$dompdf->render ();
$dompdf->stream ("Test.pdf", array ("Attachment" => false));
```

Get the image from php in base64:

```
//getIMG.php?data=1&id=123
if ($data == 1) {
    echo "data:image/".$adj->type.";base64,"
            .str_replace ("\n", "", base64_encode ($adj->imageBinary));
}
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Answer (score -1):

For showing the image, you have to go to your dompdf source file like

```
..dompdf\src\Image\Cache.php
```

In the Cache.php file, you will search .... and make chrootValid true.. by default it will be false.

```
$chrootValid = true;
```

save it and try now...
Hope it will work

Comment: Please share more details. Editing files in the `vendor` folder is never a good idea and should be avoided at **all** times