# Laravel 5 background-images doesn't show up on DOMPDF?

Tags: php, css, laravel

Here is my css code :

```
#header {
    background-image: url(../assets_frontend/images/pinpdfheader.jpg);
    width: 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size:contain;
    height:150px;
}
```

I am try to convert my html file into DOMPDF but somehow my background-images didn't show up, How to use background-images url on DOMPDF?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11360603/dompdf-not-displaying-image-generated-by-php-file

Answer (score 0):

```
.img-container {
    height:148px;
    width: 148px;
    border: 2px solid #59d;
    border-spacing: 0;
    text-align: center;
}
.img-container img {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    max-width: 148px;
    max-height: 148px;
    background-size: contain;
}

<table class="img-container"><tr><td>
    <img src="image_path.jpg">
</td></tr></table>
```